# android properties problems

Tags: android, properties, project

These are the errors given by my compiler - I have tried every thing with project properties , but still it is giving me the same error   .

```
[2012-03-04 16:24:23 - LearnAnimal1] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

Comment: what OS are you running?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16512, possible solutions are:

> Thanks a lot....I was having same problem and it's solved by :
>   Right click on your project->properties->java compiler, modify the version to 1.6
>
> I encountered this problem. I solved it by:
>   1. right clicking on the project
>   2. android tools
>   3. Add compatibility Library ...
>   and the SDK manager found 46 packages that were missing and the error was resolved
>
> I just do like
>   1. right click on the project
>   2. Android tools
>   3. Fix project property
>   Complete and enjoy